# Delphi - Passing ALT keycodes to Excel

Tags: excel, delphi

Delphi RIO - I have an Excel PlugIn written in Delphi.  I am wanting to write a routine which converts cells which have multi-line contents to single line contents, basically replacing the line break with a space characters.  I do this by replacing 'ALT 0010' to space characters.  By this, I mean I hold the ALT key down, and then hit 0010 on the numeric keypad.  This will do what I want.  I now need to program this functionality.  I can't seem to find the right way to represent ALT 0010. If I were to replace an '!' with a space in the whole spreadsheet, I could do it with the following code.

```
var
WholeSheet:  ExcelRange;
begin
...
WholeSheet := myActiveSheet.Cells;
WholeSheet.Replace('!', ' ', xlPart, xlByRows, False, False);
```

When I tried looking at this via capturing an Excel Macro, I am really confused...

```
Cells.Select
Selection.Replace What:="" & Chr(10) & "", Replacement:=" ", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

How do I represent the ALT 0010 and put it in place of the '!'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A line break is encoded (in ANSI/UTF-8) as a single byte character with value 0x0A (10 decimal).

Delphi allows you to use [control strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Fundamental_Syntactic_Elements_(Delphi)#Character_Strings) as :

```
WholeSheet.Replace(#10, ' ', xlPart, xlByRows, False, False);
```

A control string is given by the pound sign `#` followed by a *decimal* number between 0-255 (pre-Unicode Delphi) or 0-65535 (Unicode Delphi) representing the byte (or two-byte) value of the character in question.

Alternatively, you can also use the [`Chr`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Chr) function :

```
WholeSheet.Replace(Chr(10), ' ', xlPart, xlByRows, False, False);
```

The first argument in `.Replace` is an OLEVariant which can implicitly take a character literal.

Comment: That did it.  Thank you.